# Angular Tree Component init errors

Tags: angular, angular-tree-component

I'm trying to implement a very basic usage of [Angular Tree Component](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component) in my application. Angular version is 9, component version is 9.0.5.

I uncluded TreeModule into my app module's imports. Inserted this in html:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes"></tree-root>
```

And this in the TS:

```
nodes:any[] = [{name:'Test root node', children: []}];
```

It starts the app and tries to start tree component, but I see these errors:
[image]

I tried to debug, it looks like the initialization of the component and internal elements is wrong. It tries to access internal VirtualRoot and VirtualScroll before they were created.
I also tried to leave nodes collection empty and them add some nodes using:

```
this.tree.treeModel.update();
```

Then it doesn't throw exceptions on init, but it doesn't render something, although I see that nodes collection is updated inside TreeModel.

I feel like I'm missing something very basic. We're using redux, I thought it might be conflicting somehow with mobx used in tree component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in mobx version mismatch. It's listed either as a peer dependency or dependency in angular-tree-component.